# Directive render in different order

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two directives `'timeLeft'` and `'counter'` and they need to be render in order. It works fine if my html element inside `ng-repeat`. But If I have a single record, I found out the 2nd directive render first instead of First One. Here is my directives definition and html element that uses them

```
 <span>Time Left:</span> <span data-time-left="{{vm.endDate}}" data-counter=""></span>
```

1st Directive

```
app.directive('timeLeft', [function () {

    return {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'A'
    };

    function link(scope, element, attribute) {

        attribute.$observe('timeLeft', function (value) {

            var todayDate = new Date(moment().format());
            var endDate = new Date(value);
            var timeLeft = Math.round(endDate.getTime() / 1000) - Math.round(todayDate.getTime() / 1000);
            attribute.counter = timeLeft;
            element.text(moment.unix(timeLeft).format('h:mm:ss'));
        });
    }
}]);
```

2nd Directive

```
app.directive('counter', ['$interval', function ($interval) {

        return {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'A'
        };

        function link(scope, element, attribute) {
            var timeOutId;
            var startTimeStamp;
            attribute.$observe('counter', function (timeStamp) {

                startTimeStamp = timeStamp;
                timeOutId = $interval(function () {

                    startTimeStamp--;
                    element.text(moment.unix(startTimeStamp).format('h:mm:ss'));
                }, 1000);


                element.on('$destroy', function () {

                    $interval.cancel(timeOutId);
                });

            });
        }
    }]);
```

It should have to render in order to get the desired result. Any suggestion how is it possible? And why it works fine under `ng-repeat`

Here is a Plunker: `http://plnkr.co/edit/HLjH6zcQlDYqeOzujkSz?p=preview`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update

The issue is not that the directives are linking in the wrong order, but that the `$observe` events are firing in an order you weren't expecting. While there is a way to set the order in which directives will compile & link, there is no way to set which attribute related events will fire first.

A solution is to set the `priority` for both directives, such that they link in the correct order. Then in the link functions, move the blocks you have inside of anonymous sent as callbacks to `$observe` into standalone functions, which you call from $observe, but first when the link function first runs.

This will ensure that directive's initialize in the "correct" order you expect.

**Example (`timeleft` directive but very similar for `counter` as well)**

```
.directive('timeLeft', [function () {
  return {
    link: {
      pre: link
    },
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: 1
  };

  function link(scope, element, attributes) {
    var setTimeLeft = function(value) {
      // formerly in $observe anonymous function
    }

    setTimeLeft(attributes.timeLeft);

    attributes.$observe('timeLeft', function(newVal, oldVal){
      if (newVal !== oldVal && oldVal !== undefined) setTimeLeft(newVal);
    });
  }
}]);
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/cLXX0Nhc3DhEMrTtVpdf?p=preview)

#### Previous Answer (relevant, but not a complete solution)

Set a `priority` greater than zero on the directive which you need to run first:

```
app.directive('timeLeft', [function () {

    return {
        ...
        priority: 1,
        ...
    };

}]);
```

> When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM element,
>   sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives
>   are applied. The priority is used to sort the directives before their
>   compile functions get called. Priority is defined as a number.
>   Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first.

[`priority` in the Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile#directive-definition-object)

Comment: I think I might have slightly misunderstood the problem. Can you post a Fiddle/Plunker/JS Bin demonstrating it?

Comment: See the console, I logged out which directive render first

Comment: Have you checked out the time. Although it looks like it renders in right order but the time get's change before counter start.

Comment: Is this the behavior you're expecting? http://plnkr.co/edit/hINnaZM5BQSjOKBtzRrB?p=preview

Comment: Yes, exactly. But what you have changed, I did not find any changes, can you please mention

Comment: Ah, I found out, you added setTimeout..That's simple fix, but do you really think it's a proper solution or is it some kind of work around?

Comment: I think setTimeout is probably fine, but please take a look at my updated answer for a cleaner alternative.

Comment: That's look like a cleaner approach. However, I have a quick question, it seems there is no need for $observe anymore if we have moved that code block to anonymous function it works well without defining $observer. Why is it so? Check this update http://plnkr.co/edit/A0UPRK9NRszT7bAJXo5a?p=preview

Comment: I assumed you had a reason for the `$observe` beyond reading the initial attributes. If you don't then, yes, they are unnecessary, but that is outside of the scope of your original question. Please accept my answer if helped you solve your original problem.

Comment: Sure, Thank you very much for all your help. That's very supporting, I really appreciate it.

Comment: By the way, can you please help me to resolve another issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24211212/make-resource-post-like-http-post-angular